# Rolling Multiple Die in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, dice

I've been working on practice problems for my Computer Science class, and one of them reads the following:

A pair of dice is rolled repeatedly. If "box cars" (6-6) shows up, player A wins. If not, but 7 shows up twice in a row (as in, one die shows 7 and then after you roll both die again, another 7 shows up), B wins. Write a C++ program to roll a pair of dice 1000 times and output how many times A and B would have won.

So I've gotten the main backbone to the program and have tested it a few times, but every single time so far the B player shows up as winning 0 times. The A player's wins have fluctuated each time I've run the program, so I believe that A is correctly coded but any tips or debugging will be greatly appreciated. The program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int die1, die2, store = 0, awin = 0, bwin = 0;

srand(time(NULL));

for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    die1 = rand()% 6+1;
    die2 = rand()% 6+1;

    if(die1 == 6 && die2 == 6)
    {
        awin++;
    }
    else if(die1 == 7 || die2 == 7)
    {
        store = 1;
    }

    if(store == 1 && die1 == 7)
    {
        bwin++;
        store = 0;
    }
    else if(store == 1 && die2 == 7)
    {
        bwin++;
        store = 0;
    }

    store = 0;
}

cout << "A has won " << awin << " times and B has won " << bwin << " times." << endl;

system("pause");
```

}

Comment: `else if(die1 == 7)` how could a 6 sided die ever be 7?

Comment: How many sides on the dice?

Comment: I've just noticed that it's actually impossible for the die to be equal to seven, so I'm going out on a limb here and am going to say he believed the _sum_ is equal to seven, not one of the die. I feel like an utter idiot but I just had an Organic Chemistry test today as well so I'm kind of spent... Sorry for this lol.

Comment: Can I offer a tip? This is unrelated to the question as it's already been answered, but instead of starting your curly bracket on a new line after an `if`, `else if` or even a function declaration, put it immediately after the closing normal bracket. ie `int main(){` as your 5th line. It just helps save space and increase readability.

Comment: @TheWalkingCactus: You know, programmers will argue for eons over coding conventions like these.  I, for example, despise curly braces on the same line, and I will argue it to the death!

Comment: @uberwulu Really? huh, I never knew. The 2 people who have taught me both liked it like that, and I guess that rubbed off on me and I despise it on a new line. I never really questioned it... in that case, nevermind, OP. Do as you please :)

Comment: @TheWalkingCactus:  Actually, when I first started programming, I did them on a newline.  After a few months, I decided to do them on the same line, and religiously argued that way for almost a year.  Then spent the rest of my years doing it on a newline again, and which I remain partial to today.  To each his own, except on teams, in which case it's time to throw down.

Comment: @TheWalkingCactus:  With disk drives now measuring in the terabytes, is the cost of saving that much space (tabs or spaces) significant?  Also, the savings in the build process is very negligible.

Comment: It has absolutely nothing to do with the space savings at all. It's just a style thing. Which is why programmers will argue for eons ^^ nobody will ever claim that it's an efficiency thing, unless they're a severe pedant.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I agree that saving that extra carriage return isn't significant at all, I was more-so talking about style. (As Salamander said) I was taught that way, and so because of familiarity now it looks better and less strung-out to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rand() % 7` will NEVER give you a result of 7. It's the remainder of a number divided by 7, so you'll get anything between 0 and 6.

With your comment in mind, just check that `die1 + die2 == 7` and you'll be sorted.

Comment: Yeah, I've actually just noticed that the die can only go up to six, and my professor may have meant that the _sum_ be equal to seven. I feel like an idiot...

Comment: I thought that might be the case, but if that's the question verbatim, then he's at least partially at fault.

Answer (score 0):

`rand()%6+1` returns a range from 1-6.
`store` is only ever being assigned on the condition that a die rolls 7, which never happens.
`bwin` is only ever being incremented if `store` is equal to a die roll, which also never happens, since store is initialized to 0 and the conditions to re-assign it (rolling 7) can never be met.
Therefore, `bwin` is always 0 and `awin` increments only when both dice roll 6.

Answer (score 0):

Everything through this part seems correct:

```
if(die1 == 6 && die2 == 6) {
    awin++;
}
```

It's after this that things get sideways.

First, check to see if the previous roll was 7 and if the current roll matches the previous roll:

```
if(store == 7 && store == die1 + die2) {
```

If that evaluates to true, b has won:

```
    bwin++;
}
```

Then store the value of the current roll so you'll know about it on the next roll:

```
store = die1+die2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be checking each die against 7 but rather the sum of the two dice.

Try this

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    die1 = rand()% 6+1;
    die2 = rand()% 6+1;

    if(die1 == 6 && die2 == 6)
    {
        awin++;
    }
    else if (store == 7 && (die1 + die2) == 7)
    {
        bwin++;
    }

    store = die1 + die2;
}
```